# Submitting form with Ajax posts to Controller action

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to run some background validation with Ajax, but the form still posts to the controller.

**The form**

```
<form id="myForm" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="username" />
    <input type="hidden" name="password" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**The script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#myForm").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        showLoadingWindow(); // Unhides some "Logging in..." div
        $.ajax({
            url: "@actionUrl",
            type: "POST",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            cache: false,
            done: function () {
                window.location.href(@successUrl);
            },
            fail: function () {
                window.location.href(@errorUrl);
            }
        });
    });

});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't see your validation.  Is that done through the ajax call back to the server?

Comment: It is/should be done at `url: "@actionUrl"`.

Comment: Is there any error in the console? It's probably because the binding has not been executed.

Comment: @TylerNguyen There aren't any errors and things work perfectly fine if I remove the Ajax call.

Comment: Are you trying to avoid posting the form to the server? What exactly are you trying to achieve? It is not very clear.

Comment: @rae1n I am posting the form to `@actionUrl`. As that url does its things in the background, a loading window will be displayed, and when it's done, redirection will happen. However none of that really matters because all I had was a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was completely my fault for previously having commented out the `.href` URLs, because the problem is that I forgot to put quotes around them: `window.location.href("@errorUrl");` is what would've fixed it, even though the console didn't throw an error when I was missing the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

you might try changing your ajax call to use success instead of done.

```
success: function(result){
    if(result.Success){
        window.location...
    }else{
        window.location...
    }
}
```